# Lambda expression and generic interface

Tags: java, generics, lambda

So, I am currently studying lambda expressions and just came across an example with generic functional intefaces:

```
@FunctionalInterface
public interface Mapper<T> {
    int map(T source);

    public static <U> int[] mapToInt(U[] list, Mapper<? super U> mapper) {
        int[] mappedValues = new int[list.length];

        for(int i = 0; i< list.length; i++) {
            mappedValues[i] = mapper.map(list[i]);
        }

        return mappedValues;
    }
}
```

and the test code

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
        System.out.println("Mapping names to their lengths:");
        String[] names = {"David", "Li", "Doug"};
        int[] lengthMapping = Mapper.mapToInt(names, (String name) -> name.length());
        printMapping(names, lengthMapping);

    }

    public static void printMapping(Object[] from, int[] to) {
        for(int i = 0; i < from.length; i++) {
            System.out.println(from[i]  + " mapped to " + to[i]);
        }
    }
```

So, what is bothering me, in this example, we are passing an instance of the `Mapper` functional interface as a second argument to the `mapToInt` method in the test code. But, what would be the value of the formal parameter `<T>` of the `Mapper`, in this example? This seems to work, but how come is compiler able to figure this out if never specified the argument for the formal parameter?

Is it maybe because, the abstract method:

```
int map(T source);
```

uses `T` parameter, and based on the lambda expression argument, uses that as a real type for `T`?

Also, second parameter in mapToInt: `Mapper<? super U> mapper` , same question, what would be the value in this example for the type of `Mapper`,  `<? super U>` ?

Answer (score 1):

The type U is unrelated to the type T.

The type T permits to define a functional generic interface where its single abstract method requires to implement a function `T -> int`.

So one of this expression will be perfectly valid:

```
Mapper<Boolean> mapper = b -> b.hashCode(); //a function Boolean -> int
```

The type U permits you to define a generic method. So when you call `mapToInt` with a `String[]` as first parameter, the type U inferred by the compiler is `String`.

Thus you are required to provide a function `String -> int` which is exactly what `name -> name.length()` does (you can omit the type parameter of the lambda expression).

Answer (score 0):

> This seems to work, but how come is compiler able to figure this out
>   if never specified the argument for the formal parameter?

This is called *type inference.* The exact procedure is [extremely complicated](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-18.html#jls-18.5.2), but in this case the compiler is able to infer the type easily because you *do* specify it explicitly: `(String name) -> name.length()`. So what you say is true:

> based on the lambda expression argument, uses that as a real type for
>   T?

However, it is not exactly necessary in this case. This will work too:

```
int[] lengthMapping = Mapper.mapToInt(names, name -> name.length());
```

In this case observe that the compiler knows what the type parameter of the function `mapToInt` is. Indeed, the function declared with the first parameter `U[] list`, and since you pass `String[] names` as the first parameter, the compiler is able to infer that whatever `U` is, `String[]` must be convertible to `U[]` by a [widening reference conversion](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-5.html#jls-5.1.5). That is, `U` is `String` or a superclass of `String`.

Now, the second parameter is an instance of a functional interface whose method accepts something that either `U` or a superclass of `U` (that's what `Mapper<? super U>` means). At this moment the compiler basically decides "well, it might as well just be `String`" because it being a `String` wouldn't contradict anything inferred so far. Note that you can actually change the type of the lambda expression:

```
int[] lengthMapping = Mapper.mapToInt(names, (Object name) -> name.hashCode());
```

Now `T` will be `Object` because you have specified it explicitly. But since `T` must be a superclass of `U` or `U` itself it's not clear any more what exactly `U` is. `U` might be `String`, but it also might be `Object`. But guess what? It doesn't matter! Because at compile-time it has no effect and at runtime it will be `Object` anyway because of the type erasure. But if you really want, you may clarify that explicitly too:

```
int[] lengthMapping = Mapper.<Object>mapToInt(names, name -> name.hashCode());
```